# Security - Apache's websites folder inside Home folder

Tags: permissions, apache2, security

Is it secure to change `DocumentRoot` path to some folder in user's `Home` directory?

Or it's better to leave it be and using a shared group between your user and Apache server as you can see it in the following solution: [What's the best way of handling permissions for Apache 2's user www-data in /var/www?](https://serverfault.com/a/65416)

I've read a thing or two and my solution would be as follows:

1. Create a new `user` and a new `group` for Apache only (ideally, restrict shell access for that user)
2. In `httpd.conf` change User and Group directives to newly created `user` and `group`
3. Create new folder in your `Home` directory for your websites e.g `Websites\Project1\public_html`
4. Change the `public_html`'s ownership to created earlier `user` and `group`
5. Set `chmod 2775` (wtih SETGID) to folders and `chmod 664` to files (recursively, if needed)
6. Set `umask 0002`
7. Finally, add yourself to `group` created in the first step

Comment: I like the SO method. My experience is to harden this even more. See if below makes sense to you :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way (my opinion) is to use a different user for apache (www-data, apache) and use the following method:

1. create an FTP location that has the subdirectories of your website. Chroot this location. For traceability I would use different users if there is more than 1.
2. setup a cronjob (/etc/crontab with the apache user as the one executing this) with a script that scans the directory for new content every few minutes. If new content found let it make a backup of the files on the apache side (compressed tar file with username and a timestamp in the filename) of the files found on the ftp side.
3. let the cronjob copy the files over. You could finish this off with  a confirmation mail that this was done by 'user' and include a `diff` of the differences.

In case something goes wrong you can

1. track who did it.
2. what this person did.
3. undo what he did.

Do not use the documentroot for development. 1 typo can kill the website and then someone has to find this typo and fix it.